# Sound Not working on reboot

Tags: boot, drivers, sound, dual-boot

I have a Alienware m17xR4 and when I reboot from Windows 7 into 12.04 I have no sound.  The icon is there and all of the listed devices are still present just no sound.  If I reboot in 12.04 back into 12.04 it stops working.  If I reboot from 12.04 to Windows 7 the sound works fine in Windows.  The only way to fix the problem with the sound in 12.04 in to shut the computer down for 15 seconds then start it again.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to install the lastest drivers for your devices. If you didn't do it yet, follow the next steps:

- Click on the **Dash**
- Search for **Additional** and click **Additional Drivers**
- Wait a bit, and you'll see a list with all the compatible drivers for your computer. You can install your graphics card drivers (I usually install the post-release drivers) and all your other devices.
- Check if your soundcard name appears at that list, select the entry for it and click Activate. After a while, you'll have to restart your computer.

I hope it works to you, and tell us soon if it worked OK!

Comment: Unfortunately, the Additional Drivers says that there are no proprietary drivers in use on this system.  That is all that is displayed in the window except close help and a grayed out enable.